# Runtime complexity of recursive permutation function

Tags: algorithm, recursion, data-structures, time-complexity, permutation

I wrote this code that returns all the permutation of the provided string. Now I want to calculate the run-time complexity and need help in that.

The code recursively calls the `permutationRecursively` function N times (for every character of the string i.e. st) and then there are two for loops one is looping through all the permutations returns back from the recursive call (i.e. for `a` it will be ['a'] or for `ab` it will be ['ab', 'ba'] and so on) and then each pair of permutation. I am really confused about this part. What will be complexity of this specific part?

I assume that for all the recursive calls it will be `O(N)` and then for inner loops, it will be `O(A*B)`. So the total would be `O(N*A*B)`. Is it correct?

```
def permutationRecursively(st):
    if(len(st) < 2):
        return [st]
    else:
        permutations = permutationRecursively(st[0:-1])
        newPermutations = []
        wordToInsert = st[-1]
        for permutationPair in permutations:
            for index in range(len(permutationPair)+1):
                newPermutations.append(permutationPair[0:index]+wordToInsert+permutationPair[index:])          
        return newPermutations

start_time = time.time()
permutationRecursively("abbc")
print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
```

Comment: Could you please unaccept my answer. The answer provided by @Mo.B is the right answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function works by first recursively calling itself on an input of size `n-1`. Then it loops through each element of the result (of which there are `(n-1)!`), and for each element, it does `O(n²)` work (since `len(permutationPair)+1` has length `n` and the string concatenation is `O(n)`.

Hence we get the following recurrence relation for the time complexity `T(n)`:

```
T(n) = T(n-1) + (n-1)! n²
```

The asymptotic behaviour of this relation is as follows:

```
T(n) ∈ Θ((n-1)! n²) = Θ(n!n)
```

So, in particular, `T(n) ∉ O(n!)`.

Comment: Nice answer. I'm glad somebody else looked at this with discernment. I have asked the OP to unaccept my answer. As soon as this has happened I will remove it as this is the correct approach.